# Why do I get 'Can't exec "ssh" No such file or directory' when I try to use Net::SSH::Expect in Cygwin?

Tags: perl

I'm receiving the below error message when I try to execute the below statement in my code.  The path in my error message doesn't exist.  As shown below, the path is actually located in /lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22/Expect.pm.  Im unsure how Perl prepended the "usr" folder in the path.  I'm receiving a similar error message when running other code.

[image]

**Error message received:**

Can't exec "ssh" No such file or directory at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22/Expect.pm line 173.

**Snippet of my code:**

```
$ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new(
host       => "192.168.1.10",
user       => 'username',
password   => 'password',
raw_pty    => 1,
log_stdout => 1,
no_terminal => 1, 
);
my $login_output = $ssh->login();
```

**Below are my environmental variables shown using perl -V**

[image]

Comment: Did you install the openssh package when you installed Cygwin?

Comment: I'm using Net::SSH::Expect instead of OpenSSH

Comment: Net::SSH::Expect expects the ssh program to be installed and in your PATH. The Cygwin openssh package provides usr/bin/ssh.exe. I'm asking if you installed the openssh Cygwin package.

Comment: @bigtime813 @ThisSuitIsBlackNot is asking for cygwin package installation.
`Net::SSH::Expect` is perl module.

Comment: First line in the description of the documentation: "This module is a wrapper to the ssh executable that is available in your system's $PATH."

Comment: Thanks...that fixed it...I assumed perl would install the required dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Net::SSH::Expect](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Net-SSH-Expect/lib/Net/SSH/Expect.pod) requires SSH to be installed. It is not either/or.

The first line in the module's [description](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Net-SSH-Expect/lib/Net/SSH/Expect.pod#DESCRIPTION) states:

> This module is a wrapper to the ssh executable that is available in your system's $PATH.

So you have to install Cygwin's SSH package.

Comment: Thanks...that fixed it...I assumed perl would install the required dependencies.

Comment: @bigtime813 Typically, that isn't the case for distributions that wrap external libraries due to compatibility issues, license issues etc.

Comment: If you installed Net::SSH::Expect using the Cygwin package manager, yeah, it should have installed `ssh` (but the packager would have had to add that dependency manually). If you installed Net::SSH::Expect through `cpan`/`cpanm`/etc, it should have failed without the dependency (if it has useful tests). (Did you force the install? Don't do that!!!!!!)

Comment: @ikegami *Should* is the key word. The author [didn't put in any checks for the ssh binary](https://metacpan.org/source/BNEGRAO/Net-SSH-Expect-1.09/Makefile.PL), not even in the [tests](https://metacpan.org/source/BNEGRAO/Net-SSH-Expect-1.09/t/Net-SSH-Expect.t).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot What's more surprising is that there's only a single individual test for the whole distribution.

Comment: Yay completely useless test suite! Ok, I didn't do [better](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/IKEGAMI/WWW-Kickstarter-v1.8.0/t/) in WWW::Kickstarter. At least I use it daily, so I'll know if it stops working :)

Comment: @stevieb I should have put "tests" in quotes ;)

Answer (score 1):

---

> *I'm unsure how Perl prepended the "usr" folder in the path*

Cygwin is a unix emulation environment. Part of that includes emulating a unix file system. Cygwin programs don't use `C:`, but the virtual `/` directory. What you see as `C:\cygwin64\lib\perl5\site_perl\5.22\Expect.pm` is available in the cygwin environment as `/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22/Expect.pm`.

This has nothing to do with your problem. It's `ssh` that can't be found, not `/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22/Expect.pm`.

So run Cygwin's `setup` program and install `ssh`.